# Error using SVD to calculate a covariance matrix in R

Tags: r, svd

I am trying to use SVD decomposition to calculate a covariance matrix however it is not working correctly.
I have built the following function.

Can anyone help point me to the mistake I have made.

Thanks in advance

```
svdcov = function(x){
           svdmat = svd(x)


## d is the singular values sometimes denoted as s
## u is left singular
## v is right singular
dvec = matrix(data=NA,nrow=length(x),ncol=1)
dvec[,1] = svdmat$d
covmat = t(t(svdmat$v%*%dvec)%*%t(svdmat$u)%*%svdmat$u)%*%t(dvec)%*%svdmat$v   
        colnames(covmat) = colnames(x)
        rownames(covmat) = colnames(x)
        return(covmat)

}
```

Comment: Why is `nrow=11` in `dvec`? what dimension do you expect in `x`?

Comment: the x it was being applied to was dim(11) to generalize nrow should be length(x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The singular value decomposition is `X=UDV'`.
If you want to compute `X'X`,
that would be `(UDV')'(UDV')`, i.e., 
`VDU'UDV'`, i.e., `V D^2 V'` (`U` is orthogonal and `D` diagonal).

```
f <- function(x) { 
  s <- svd(x)
  v <- s$v
  d <- diag(s$d)  # It is a vector: transform it to a diagonal matrix
  v %*% d^2 %*% t(v)
}
x <- matrix( rnorm(200), nc=4 )
stopifnot( all( abs( f(x) - t(x) %*% x ) < 1e-12 ) )
```

To have the variance matrix, you still need to subtract the mean of all the columns, 
and divide by the number of observations.

```
stopifnot( all( abs( 
    var(x) - 
    f(scale(x, scale=FALSE)) / (nrow(x)-1)
  ) < 1e-12
) )
```

Comment: So my function should look like:  'code' svpieces <- function(x) 
 { 
  s <- svd(x)
  v <- s$v
  d <- diag(s$d)  # It is a vector: transform it to a diagonal matrix
  v %*% d^2 %*% t(v)
}

svdcov = function(x){
return(abs(var(x) -  svpieces(scale(x, scale=FALSE)) / (nrow(x)-1)))

} 'code'

Comment: No: `abs(var(x) - ...) < 1e-12` was just there to check 
that the result was equal to `var(x)`. 
You only need `f(scale(x, scale=FALSE)) / (nrow(x)-1)`.